How to check the checkbox value contains string value from input in JavaScript
I am looking for a solution like that I have a group of check boxes and on top of that there is a textbox and checkbox has to filter as we type on the textbox. If we type "Y", the checkboxes with values which contains or Starts with "Y" should be displayed. Other checkboxes will be hidden or collapsed.
How to do this in JavaScript? If you run this code, you can see a table and click on the header column, it will display a filter grid.


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table th").click(function() {
    showFilterOption(this);
  });
});

var arrayMap = {};

function showFilterOption(tdObject) {
  var filterGrid = $(tdObject).find(".filter");
  if (filterGrid.is(":visible")) {
    filterGrid.hide();
    return;
  }
  $(".filter").hide();

  var index = 0;
  filterGrid.empty();
  var allSelected = true;

  filterGrid.append('<div><input id="searchtext" type="text" placeholder="Search" style="width: 70% !important"></div>');
  filterGrid.append('<div id="checkBoxes">');
  filterGrid.append('<label><input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" value = "ALL" >ALL</label>')


  var ColorsAvailable = document.getElementById('checkBoxes');
  var check_value = new Array();
  check_value[0] = "Yellow";
  check_value[1] = "Red";
  check_value[2] = "Green";

  var color, p, br;

  for (var count in check_value) {
    color = document.createElement("input");
    color.value = check_value[count];
    color.type = "checkbox";
    color.id = "color" + count;
    p = document.createElement("span");
    p.innerHTML = check_value[count] + ": ";
    br = document.createElement("br");
    ColorsAvailable.appendChild(p);
    ColorsAvailable.appendChild(color);
    ColorsAvailable.appendChild(br);
    filterGrid.append(ColorsAvailable);
  }

  filterGrid.append('</div>');

  if (!allSelected) {
    filterGrid.find("#all").removeAttr("checked");
  }

  filterGrid.append('<div style="text-align: center"><input id="close" type="button" value="Close" style="width: 40%"/><input id="ok" type="button" value="Ok" style="width: 40%"/></div>');
  filterGrid.show();

  var $stxt = filterGrid.find("input[type='text']");
  var $closeBtn = filterGrid.find("#close");
  var $okBtn = filterGrid.find("#ok");
  var $checkElems = filterGrid.find("input[type='checkbox']");
  var $gridItems = filterGrid.find(".grid-item");
  var $all = filterGrid.find("#all");

  $closeBtn.click(function() {
    filterGrid.hide();
    return false;
  });

  $("#searchtext").keyup(function() {
    var inputValue = $('#searchtext').val();
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('value').Contains(inputValue)) {

      } else {
        this.checkbox.Hide(); // here i want to hide
        // that check box
      }

    });

  });


  $okBtn.click(function() {
    filterGrid.find(".grid-item").each(function(ind, ele) {
      if ($(ele).find("input").is(":checked")) {
        $(arrayMap[ind]).show();
      } else {
        $(arrayMap[ind]).hide();
      }
    });

    filterGrid.hide();
    return false;
  });

  $checkElems.click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $gridItems.click(function(event) {
    var chk = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
    $(chk).prop("checked", !$(chk).is(":checked"));
  });

  $all.change(function() {
    var chked = $(this).is(":checked");
    filterGrid.find(".grid-item [type='checkbox']").prop("checked", chked);
  });

  filterGrid.click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  return filterGrid;
}
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: overlay;
}

th,
thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: #1f2d54;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-break: break-word;
  height: 45px;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 30vh;
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: small;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #1f2d54;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.filter input {
  margin: 5px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 10%;
}

input.largerCheckbox {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style='padding: 8px;'>
  <tr>
    <th index=0>
      Email
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=1>
      Name
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=2>
      Level
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=3>
      Location
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 2</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 3</td>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 3</td>
    <td>Name 3</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>




Please add the relevant html to your question.

How is your script not doing as expected? Is there an error in your dev console?

@mykaf code added. please help

Your dev console says ($(...).attr(...).Contains is not a function

@mykaf yes i know Contains is not a function. I am expecting something like - Left(checkbox.value) == txtsearch. I dont know how to do that. Please help.

I think startsWith might be helpful for you.

@mykaf it is not working. if ($(this).attr('value').startsWith(inputValue)) {
alert(value);
}

"it's not working" isn't particular helpful for debugging. What does it do? Is there an error message?

Pick a lane; either use jQuery or DOM functions, not a mixture; you're just going to end up confusing yourself (and others). Likewise, capitalize function names or don't. Most style guides recommend using camel case for JavaScript, meaning the first letter is always lower case. Prefix your jQuery object-containing variables with a dollar sign or don't, but be consistent. The mixture just makes it harder to read the code.

I had to change your code a bit - I wrapped the checkboxes in labels and toggle those. You still need to toggle all back when checking "all"
You have issues with duplicate IDs


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table th").click(function() {
    showFilterOption(this);
  });
});

var arrayMap = {};

function showFilterOption(tdObject) {
  var filterGrid = $(tdObject).find(".filter");
  if (filterGrid.is(":visible")) {
    filterGrid.hide();
    return;
  }
  $(".filter").hide();

  var index = 0;
  filterGrid.empty();
  var allSelected = true;

  filterGrid.append('<div><input id="searchtext" type="text" placeholder="Search" style="width: 70% !important"></div>');
  filterGrid.append('<div id="checkBoxes">');
  filterGrid.append('<label><input type="checkbox" id="all" class="largerCheckbox" value="ALL">ALL</label>')


  var ColorsAvailable = document.getElementById('checkBoxes');
  var check_value = new Array();
  check_value[0] = "Yellow";
  check_value[1] = "Red";
  check_value[2] = "Green";

  var color, label, br;

  for (var count in check_value) {
    color = document.createElement("input");
    color.value = check_value[count];
    color.type = "checkbox";
    color.id = "color" + count;
    label = document.createElement("label");
    label.innerHTML = check_value[count] + ": ";
    br = document.createElement("br");
    label.appendChild(color);
    label.appendChild(br);
    ColorsAvailable.appendChild(label);
    filterGrid.append(ColorsAvailable);
  }

  filterGrid.append('</div>');

  if (!allSelected) {
    filterGrid.find("#all").removeAttr("checked");
  }

  filterGrid.append('<div style="text-align: center"><input id="close" type="button" value="Close" style="width: 40%"/><input id="ok" type="button" value="Ok" style="width: 40%"/></div>');
  filterGrid.show();

  var $stxt = filterGrid.find("input[type='text']");
  var $closeBtn = filterGrid.find("#close");
  var $okBtn = filterGrid.find("#ok");
  var $checkElems = filterGrid.find("input[type='checkbox']");
  var $gridItems = filterGrid.find(".grid-item");
  var $all = filterGrid.find("#all");

  $closeBtn.click(function() {
    filterGrid.hide();
    return false;
  });

  $("#searchtext").on('input',function() {
    let inputValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    let allChecked = $('#all').is(':checked');
    $("#checkBoxes input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
      const val = $(this).attr('value').toLowerCase()
      $(this).closest('label').toggle(allChecked || val.includes(inputValue));
    });

  });


  $okBtn.click(function() {
    filterGrid.find(".grid-item").each(function(ind, ele) {
      if ($(ele).find("input").is(":checked")) {
        $(arrayMap[ind]).show();
      } else {
        $(arrayMap[ind]).hide();
      }
    });

    filterGrid.hide();
    return false;
  });

  $checkElems.click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $gridItems.click(function(event) {
    var chk = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
    $(chk).prop("checked", !$(chk).is(":checked"));
  });

  $all.on('click', function() {
    var chked = $(this).is(":checked");
    filterGrid.find("[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", chked);
  });

  filterGrid.click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  return filterGrid;
}
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: overlay;
}

th,
thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: #1f2d54;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-break: break-word;
  height: 45px;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 30vh;
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: small;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #1f2d54;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.filter input {
  margin: 5px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 10%;
}

input.largerCheckbox {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style='padding: 8px;'>
  <tr>
    <th index=0>
      Email
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=1>
      Name
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=2>
      Level
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=3>
      Location
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 2</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 3</td>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 3</td>
    <td>Name 3</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>




Thanks very much for your answer. But when we click on ALL, the other checkboxes are not checked. Besides, when we type "a" on the text box, it is not filtering. Could you please provide solution for these issues as well. Thanks.

Yes, I did not do the "all" What do you mean by"a" You have Y(ellow), R(ed), G)reen

I fixed "all" you did not have anything with id="all"

@KitKat I do not understand what is missing from the filtering here. If you need the OK to then filter the columns that is just continuation of the script I already wrote
