Filtering Checkboxes and Tables using Javascript
I was working with a html table where I need to filter two things. One is there is a table with data and when we click on column header and a filter grid will be displayed in which we can see a textbox and below that there are check boxes. I am looking a solution like when we type on the textbox, the checkboxes will filtered by the text input and after that click on OK button the table will be filtered.
Here what happens is, when i type any letter in the textbox, the checkboxes with value contains that letter will be displayed and after that i click on OK button, the checked items will be displayed on the below grid.
Now nothing happens. When we click on the header column, a small filter grid will be displayed as shown in the below image. When enter any character in the textbox, the checkboxes which contains the value of the textbox text will be displayed other check boxes will be hidden.
After that, if we click on any check boxes, the below big table grid will be filtered like excel filter. I want to have these 2 functionalities in this solution.

Code is like shown below


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table th").click(function() {
    showFilterOption(this);
  });
});

var arrayMap = {};

function showFilterOption(tdObject) {
  var filterGrid = $(tdObject).find(".filter");
  if (filterGrid.is(":visible")) {
    filterGrid.hide();
    return;
  }
  $(".filter").hide();

  var index = 0;
  filterGrid.empty();
  var allSelected = true;

  filterGrid.append('<div><input id="searchtext" type="text" placeholder="Search" style="width: 70% !important"></div>');

  filterGrid.append('<div><input id="all" type="checkbox" style="width: 10% !important" checked>All</div>');

  var $rows = $(tdObject).parents("table").find("tr");
  var values = [];

  $rows.each(function(ind, ele) {
    if (ind > 0) {
      var currentTd = $(ele).children()[$(tdObject).attr("index")];
      if (!values.includes(currentTd.innerHTML)) {
        values.push(currentTd.innerHTML);
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("grid-item");
        var str = $(ele).is(":visible") ? "checked" : "";
        if ($(ele).is(":hidden")) {
          allSelected = false;
        }
        div.innerHTML = '<br><input type="checkbox" ' + str + " >" + currentTd.innerHTML;
        filterGrid.append(div);
        arrayMap[index] = ele;
        index++;
      }
    }
  });

  if (!allSelected) {
    filterGrid.find("#all").removeAttr("checked");
  }

  filterGrid.append('<div style="text-align: center"><input id="close" type="button" value="Close" style="width: 40%"/><input id="ok" type="button" value="Ok" style="width: 40%"/></div>');
  filterGrid.show();

  var $stxt = filterGrid.find("input[type='text']");
  var $closeBtn = filterGrid.find("#close");
  var $okBtn = filterGrid.find("#ok");
  var $checkElems = filterGrid.find("input[type='checkbox']");
  var $gridItems = filterGrid.find(".grid-item");
  var $all = filterGrid.find("#all");

  $closeBtn.click(function() {
    filterGrid.hide();
    return false;
  });

  $("#searchtext").on('input', function() {

  });

  $okBtn.click(function() {
    filterGrid.find(".grid-item").each(function(ind, ele) {
      if ($(ele).find("input").is(":checked")) {
        $(arrayMap[ind]).show();
      } else {
        $(arrayMap[ind]).hide();
      }
    });

    filterGrid.hide();
    return false;
  });

  $checkElems.click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $gridItems.click(function(event) {
    var chk = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
    $(chk).prop("checked", !$(chk).is(":checked"));
  });

  $all.change(function() {
    var chked = $(this).is(":checked");
    filterGrid.find(".grid-item [type='checkbox']").prop("checked", chked);
  });

  filterGrid.click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  return filterGrid;
}
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: overlay;
}

th,
thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: #1f2d54;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-break: break-word;
  height: 45px;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 40vh;
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: small;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #1f2d54;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.filter input {
  margin: 5px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 10%;
}

input.largerCheckbox {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table style='padding: 8px;'>
  <tr>
    <th index=0>
      Email
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=1>
      Name
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=2>
      Level
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=3>
      Location
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 2</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 3</td>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 3</td>
    <td>Name 3</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>




Your question is unclear; how is your code not working as expected?

You have shared what you are working on, but .... what is the question?

@trincot i have edited the question and image is added

I fixed most of your questions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78731609/how-to-check-the-checkbox-value-contains-string-value-from-input-in-javascript - why not use my changed code as basis?

@mplungjan sorry bro. That is not suitable for our need. Our manager actually wants this requirement.  Kindly help me. I need 2 things. 1. filter in small filter grid on the header column and 2. filter the main big grid as per the checkbox clicked. My understanding was wrong when my manager told me. Please help.

My script filters the checkboxes, so that takes care of 1, no?

@mplungjan Here each check boxes are inside the each div elements. So that script will not filter the checkboxes here. I tried with your script. But It is not working. Please help sir

I am. It is a lot of work. I will save what I have so far

This is a work in progress. I have added my previous solution and am working on the toggling of the table rows


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table th").click(function() {
    showFilterOption(this);
  });
});

var arrayMap = {};

function showFilterOption(tdObject) {
  var filterGrid = $(tdObject).find(".filter");
  if (filterGrid.is(":visible")) {
    filterGrid.hide();
    return;
  }
  $(".filter").hide();

  var index = 0;
  filterGrid.empty();
  var allSelected = true;

  filterGrid.append('<div><input id="searchtext" type="text" placeholder="Search" style="width: 70% !important"></div>');

  filterGrid.append('<div><input id="all" type="checkbox" style="width: 10% !important" checked>All</div>');

  var $rows = $(tdObject).parents("table").find("tr");
  var values = [];

  // this is not elegant and does not work as expected.
  $rows.each(function(ind, ele) {
    if (ind > 0) {
      var currentTd = $(ele).children()[$(tdObject).attr("index")];
      var val = currentTd.innerHTML;
      if (!values.includes(val)) {
        values.push(currentTd.innerHTML);
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("grid-item");
        var str = $(ele).is(":visible") ? "checked" : "";
        if ($(ele).is(":hidden")) {
          allSelected = false;
        }
        div.innerHTML = `<br><label><input type="checkbox" value="${val}" ${str}>${val}</label>`;
        filterGrid.append(div);
        arrayMap[index] = ele; // this does not work as expected
        index++;
      }
    }
  });

  if (!allSelected) {
    filterGrid.find("#all").removeAttr("checked");
  }

  filterGrid.append('<div style="text-align: center"><input id="close" type="button" value="Close" style="width: 40%"/><input id="ok" type="button" value="Ok" style="width: 40%"/></div>');
  filterGrid.show();

  var $stxt = filterGrid.find("input[type='text']");
  var $closeBtn = filterGrid.find("#close");
  var $okBtn = filterGrid.find("#ok");
  var $checkElems = filterGrid.find("input[type='checkbox']");
  var $gridItems = filterGrid.find(".grid-item");
  var $all = filterGrid.find("#all");
  var $search = $("#searchtext");

  $closeBtn.click(function() {
    filterGrid.hide();
    return false;
  });

  const checkSearch = function(inputValue) {
    inputValue = inputValue.toLowerCase();
    //let allChecked = $('#all').is(':checked');
    $checkElems.each(function() {
      const val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      //$(this).closest('.grid-item').toggle(allChecked || val.includes(inputValue));
      $(this).closest('.grid-item').toggle(val.includes(inputValue));
    });
  };

  $search.on('input', function() {
    checkSearch($(this).val())
  });
  $okBtn.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const map = $checkElems
      .filter(function() { return this.checked;})
      .map(function() { return this.value.toLowerCase(); })
      .get();

    $("table tbody tr").each(function() {
      let $row = $(this);
      let found = $row.find('td').toArray().some(td => {
        let cellText = $(td).text().trim().toLowerCase();
        let matchFound = map.some(mapItem => cellText.includes(mapItem)); // Check if any map item is a substring of cellText
        // console.log(map, cellText, matchFound);
        return matchFound;
      });
      // let alwaysShow = map.length > 0 && map[0] === 'on';
      // console.log(alwaysShow || found, $row.text())
      //$row.toggle(alwaysShow || found);
      $row.toggle(found);

    });
    filterGrid.hide();
  });



  $checkElems.click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  const $allChecks = $('.filter div.grid-item input[type=checkbox]')
  .on('click', function() {
    const checked = $allChecks.filter(function() { return this.checked }).get();
    console.log(checked.length,$allChecks.length)
    $all.prop('checked',checked.length === $allChecks.length);
  });

  $all.on('click', function() {
    var chked = $(this).is(":checked");
    filterGrid.find("[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", chked);
    checkSearch($search.val());
  });

  filterGrid.click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  return filterGrid;
}
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: overlay;
}

th,
thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: #1f2d54;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-break: break-word;
  height: 45px;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 40vh;
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: small;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #1f2d54;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.filter input {
  margin: 5px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 10%;
}

input.largerCheckbox {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1px;
}


/* For Stackoverflow console */

.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 40px
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table style='padding: 8px;'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th index=0>
        Email
        <div class="filter"></div>
      </th>
      <th index=1>
        Name
        <div class="filter"></div>
      </th>
      <th index=2>
        Level
        <div class="filter"></div>
      </th>
      <th index=3>
        Location
        <div class="filter"></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Email 1</td>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td>Level 1</td>
      <td>Location 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email 1</td>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td>Level 1</td>
      <td>Location 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email 2</td>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td>Level 2</td>
      <td>Location 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email 3</td>
      <td>Name 2</td>
      <td>Level 2</td>
      <td>Location 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email 3</td>
      <td>Name 3</td>
      <td>Level 1</td>
      <td>Location 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email 1</td>
      <td>Name 2</td>
      <td>Level 2</td>
      <td>Location 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




thanks very much. One suggestion is when typing in the textbox, filtering is not working if the checkboxes are checked. I waiting for your full solution.

Took me forever to figure out your collection is not the actual table rows. I added thead and tbody and get the rows in the OK button click

Thanks very much sir. You saved me. Please correct the issue of cannot filter when we type in the textbox, filter is not working if the checkboxes are checked. Please help.

I have improved this. I will stop this now. I have spent too much time and it would have been easier to write from scratch
